# Bash script for copying files to subdirectories named after the file´s owner

Tags: bash, scripts, directory, copy

I need to write a bash script which copies files from a folder to subfolders named after the files. For example, there is a common directory "For all", inside there are various files and directories. Files have names with the name of the owner plus some further symbols like tom1, tom2, tom3,... or scott1, scott2, scott3. Subfolders are named after the owners: tom and scott. I need to write a script to copy all files in the dir "For all" to the their resprective subfolders. This is my script.

```
#!/bin/bash
forall=/home/anastasia/Scripts
cd $forall
for file in $forall
 do
        if [ -d $file ]
          then
                continue
          fi
          if [ -e $file ]
          then
                owner='ls -l $file | grep "^-" | awk {'print $£3'}'
                $file=$owner*   
                cp $file $forall/$owner
                chown $owner $forall/$owner/$file
        fi
done
```

What is wrong with my script? It does not do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the fact that

```
for file in $forall
```

will execute the loop only once, with `$file` set to the *directory* `/home/anastasia/Scripts`, the fundamental problem  is that

```
owner='ls -l $file | grep "^-" | awk {'print $£3'}'
```

assigns the literal string `ls -l $file | grep "^-" | awk {print` to the variable `owner` (and then attempts to execute `$£3}` as a command).

Presumably you intended the outer quotes to be command substitution *backticks* (and the `£3` to be plain `3`):

```
owner=`ls -l $file | grep "^-" | awk {'print $3'}`
```

however the modern way would use `$(...)` instead:

```
owner=$(ls -l $file | grep "^-" | awk {'print $3'})
```

However that's a terrible way to find a file's owner; instead I'd recommend

```
owner=$(stat -c %U -- "$file")
```

Apart from that, remember to quote your variable expansions, so something like (untested):

```
#!/bin/bash

forall=/home/anastasia/Scripts

for file in "$forall"/*
do
  if [ -d "$file" ]; then
    continue
  fi
  if [ -e "$file" ]; then
    owner=$(stat -c %U -- "$file")
    cp -n "$file" "$forall/$owner"/
    chown "$owner" "$forall/$owner/$file"
  fi
done
```

Note that you should be able to eliminate the `chown` by adding  appropriate options for `cp` (perhaps `-p` to preserve mode,ownership,timestamps).

Comment: Thank you so much for the valuable feedback! The way you suggest with cp -p and owner=$(stat -c %U --"$file") is more elegant, indeed. I have made the necessary changes, and it has worked with one user. I will look into it further.